# 2014 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Ask Ubuntu's [4th moderator election](https://askubuntu.com/election/4) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: seth] [image: mitch]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://askubuntu.com/election/4), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/4675138071035904/0).

Comment: Congratulations to both new moderators, and thanks to everyone who volunteered to run for the election!

Comment: Congrats! As Jorge said, thanks to everyone who put in the effort to run, and additional thanks to everyone who voted.  Best way to keep the community strong.

Comment: Cool, congratz to the the new ugly faces joining us! Hope we can make you feel at home.

Comment: @Seth: I voted for you, now upvote all my questions and answers! :D Congratulations, both of you! :)

Comment: Now Now.. don't we get those fancy pivot tables? :P

Comment: Pivot tables? Donno 'bout any of that, @Minato. There's a summary report you might find helpful linked abovce.

Comment: Very glad to have you as our new overlords.

Comment: Hey congratulations to the both of you! It's been great to see both of your contributions over the past year or so. I'm sure you will do an even great(er) job helping the community going forward.

Comment: congratulations we trust in you

Comment: Wow!! That awesome moment to see both my selections as **mods**. I wish both of you good luck in all your future endeavors.

Comment: M... could this get un-featured, I think everyone knows about the new mods after 6 weeks. Or we will wait until the 8?

Comment: Removing [meta-tag:featured] is the new mods' job, @bra